# Which solvers should I use to solve large, but extremely sparse LP problems with 100-500 thousand variables?

Tags: linear-programming, constraint, cbc, glpk

I would like to solve the following type of LP problems:

[image]

where *M* and *N* are very large numbers, they are on the order of a few hundreds of thousands and tens of thousands, respectively.

As is clear from the above formulation, each constraint links only a few variables, leading to an extremely sparse coefficient matrix.

Which methods and (free) libraries do you suggest for solving this issue very effectively (within a few minutes)? Is there one which can start from a known feasible solution provided by the user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the best-performing free LP solvers exploiting sparsity is HiGHS (https://github.com/ERGO-Code/HiGHS). It allows passing a starting point.

For comparing relative performance of a number of LP solvers on a standardized test set, take a look at the Mittelmann benchmarks (https://plato.asu.edu/ftp/lpopt.html)

Answer (score 5):

Based on the Mittelmann benchmarks, I would agree that HiGHS is a contender, as is [Clp](https://github.com/coin-or/Clp) (which is faster than HiGHS on some test problems, slower on others). You might also want to look at [SCIP](https://www.scipopt.org/), which is highly regarded as a mixed integer program solver but will certainly solve LPs.